# net use command: delete fails due to files in use

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file that runs overnight on our Windows server.  It maps 2 network drives and does some file copying and zipping.  At the end of the script, it removes the network drives.  However, on occasion, the job is not completing.  I review the logs and it shows that my .bat file is prompting for a confirmation on the following line due to the drive in use.

```
net use F: /d
```

It was suggested to add /y to the end of the script to handle the prompt.  However, I would like to confirm that the drive truly is still not in use.
Is there a way to keep attempting to remove the drive until it is successful without prompting?

Comment: You could use `ping` to insert a delay before attempting to run the command. But what's the motivation for removing the network drive? Why not just leave it mapped?

Comment: It is a secure server for a bank.  We are not allowed to keep network drives mapped after execution of scripts.  the /persistent switch can't be used when we map the drive either, otherwise I wouldn't be mapping them in the first place.
A ping command would create a delay, but it may still prompt.

Comment: Well, I mean you could use `/n` instead of `/y`, which would answer no to the prompt. Then, keep delaying and retrying until it is successful. You'd want to add a time-out to handle the case where it never succeeded, I suspect.

Comment: You should ask this question on superuser or serverfault.